# Define the function $F\mathop: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ by $\displaystyle{F(x):= \mu \left((-\infty,x] \right)}$. Prove the following.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, $\mu$ is a
measure on ${\cal B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R}) <\infty$).  Define the function $F\mathop: \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ by $\displaystyle{F(x):= \mu \left((-\infty,x]
\right)}$.  Prove:

1. $F$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $F$ is right-continuous.
3. $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = \mu
   (\mathbb{R})}$.
4. If $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

My progress:

At the moment, I have only been able to prove (1). Here is my attempt:

Suppose that $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$. Then we have
$$(-\infty,x] \subseteq (-\infty,y].$$
It follows from the Monotonicity of $\mu$ that
$$F(x) = \mu((-\infty,x]) \leq \mu((-\infty,y]) = F(y).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{x_n\}$ decreases to $x$ then $(-\infty,x_n]$ decreases to $(-\infty,x]$ so $\mu (-\infty,x_n] \to \mu (-\infty,x]$. This proves 2).

Since $(-\infty,x]$ increases to $\mathbb R$ as $x$increases to $\infty$ we get $\mu (-\infty,x]$ tends to $\mu (\mathbb  R)$. Also $(-\infty,x]$ decreases to the empty set as $x$ de creases to $-\infty$ so $F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$. This proves 3).

If $\{x_n\}$ increases (strictly) to $x$ then $(-\infty,x_n]$ increases to $(-\infty,x)$ so $\mu (-\infty,x_n] \to \mu (-\infty,x)$. Hence $\mu (-\infty,x_n]$ tends to $\mu (-\infty,x)$ which is $\mu (-\infty,x]- \mu \{x\}$. 4) follows easily from this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Each seems too simple.

Comment: @johnny133253 each one is that simple if you have the right tools from measure theory.

Comment: Which tools are being used?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a finite measure then $\mu (A_n) \to \mu(A)$ whenever $A_n$ increases or decreases to $A$.  This is the only tool you require. @johnny133253

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.